# Was Kyle Reese the original father of John Conner

Tags: the-terminator-series

There was an episode of *The Twilight Zone* involving time travel and as it turned out some things can be changed but other events can't and it seems to me it's possible to avoid the time paradox.

For example, at first someone else was the father and Sarah raised him by herself. At some point Skynet is created starts the war and after losing sends the terminator back in time to kill her. Kyle goes back in time and becomes the father of John creating the time loop.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40529/was-kyle-reese-always-john-connors-father?rq=1), and by extension, of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37193/how-was-skynet-created-in-the-original-timeline).

Comment: @F1Krazy You have enough reputation to close vote yourself so if you're confident it's a duplicate you probably should.

Comment: @huginn -  for one thing, you shouldn't take any time travel rules in any SF story as being guides for what is possible in other stories or in reality, unless those rules are absolutely believable.  Second, for John Connor to be same person in both time lines he must have the same two parents in both timelines and they must have sex at the exact same instant of time, in order to have even a small chance that John Connor will have the same genes and thus possibly have the same personality.  It is utterly impossible for two John Connors with different fathers to be the same person.

Comment: @M. A. Golding The  John Connor  that existed in the original timeline doesn't have to be the exact same  John Connor  that existed in the movies. Only 3 things matters, his name is John his mother  is Sara and he led the resistance. What I am proposing is in the  original  timeline someone  else was the father and John acquired the skills to lead the resistance and John can learn those skills any number of ways. When Kyle went back in time he  became the father and we now have a different John Connor to lead the resistance